# Creating transactions with Transaction Data to Metamask

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

We can use transaction data to submit any Ethereum transaction using Metamask, right? Not only ERC20 transfers, right?
Does anyone knows how can I generate hexadecimal transaction data to Metamask from users inputs in my dApp?

Shall I use this code?

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    name: 'myMethod',
    type: 'function',
    inputs: [{
        type: 'uint256',
        name: 'myNumber'
    },{
        type: 'string',
        name: 'myString'
    }]
}, ['2345675643', 'Hello!%']);
```

> "0x24ee0097000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008bd02b7b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000748656c6c6f212500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

Is there any pitfall I should know?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web3.js and Metamask to submit transactions to your contracts in a way that the user would expect, and without needing to get into the nitty-gritty of creating raw transaction data.

First thing you need to do is set Metamask as your Web3 provider as documented in their instructions:

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

  // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
  startApp()

})
```

Then you need to import your contract with the ABI into your JavaScript context:

```
abi = // some ABI JSON;
address = // some contract address as string;
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

Finally, you just need to call your contract function:

```
myContract.methods.myMethod(123, 'Hello').send({ from: "from address here"})
.then(function(receipt){
    // Do something after metamask ui
});
```

This should prompt the Metamask UI to ask the user to sign the transaction, and hopefully do what you are looking for in a really simple way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that I can hadle transactions in such a way in my dApp. But, I have seen some applications that use transaction data in Metamask (primablock). So, I am trying to understand how this works.

Comment: I see. In this case, yes, you can use the `data` parameter to interact with any contract. The magic happening behind the scenes is described [here](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#transmitting-a-data-payload-to-an-eoa-or-contract). What you are doing looks correct, so as long as the user send that data payload to the right contract address, you should get the expected behavior.